# Can a standard 15A receptacle outlet handle a 15A draw on each outlet simultaneously?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

For more color, I have 2x UPSes that are each rated at 15A (each has their own built in 15A fuse).  The current plan is to install a dedicated 30A circuit breaker and use 10/2 NM to a regular double outlet 15A receptacle.  I'm assuming that since the receptacle can be run with 2 hot wires by breaking the tab that it is designed to handle 15A at each outlet and not as a whole.  Just wanted to run this by someone else.  I searched around and didn't see any answers for this question posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No can do. You can't have a 30 Amp breaker feeding 15 Amp outlets. You can run a 14/3 NM and have a MWBC with two hot legs,different legs, a neutral and a double pole 15 Amp breaker. You can pull 15 amps on each plug because being on two different legs the outlet only sees 15 amps at a time. using the same leg would put 30 amps on the outlet and that would way overload it. Naturally, this circuit will be grounded. 12/3 NB and a 20 Amp breaker would be better

Comment: @SteveSether -- wrong, the breakers still need to be tied since they're feeding things on the same yoke/gang

Comment: @SteveSether -- so that someone working on the receptacle doesn't get surprised when they check a receptacle, turn it off, and go to work on things only to find the other half's still live -- this is NEC 210.7

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I'll go find a double-pole 20A afci breaker than and some 12/3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing a new circuit to run two 15 A UPS, then you should be using a 20 A double-pole breaker, #12/3 copper wire, to a 20 A duplex receptacle in a MWBC (tab on hot side broken).

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think they are, but it's not relevant since the NEC 210.21(B)(3) prohibits dangerously trying to protect a 15A receptacle with a 30A breaker.

If you look at a trip curve for a circuit breaker it can hold 2x it's rating for 2 minutes. 60A is a lot of smooke from a 15A device.